# create multiple objects at the same time

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have this view that creates a form with groups and exercises.
How can I do to be able to create more groups and exercises in the template?

views.py

```
@login_required
def creaScheda(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = CreaSchedaForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   schedaName = form.cleaned_data['nome_scheda']
   scheda = form.save(commit = False)
   scheda.utente = request.user
   scheda.save()

   gruppi = DatiGruppi(
    giorni_settimana = form.cleaned_data['giorni_settimana'],
    dati_gruppo = form.cleaned_data['dati_gruppo'],
    gruppi_scheda = Schede.objects.get(nome_scheda = schedaName)
   ) 
   gruppi.save()

   esercizi = DatiEsercizi(
    serie = form.cleaned_data['serie'],
    ripetizione = form.cleaned_data['ripetizione'],
    peso = form.cleaned_data['peso'],
    gruppo_single = DatiGruppi.objects.get(gruppi_scheda = scheda.id),
    dati_esercizio = form.cleaned_data['dati_esercizio']
   )
   esercizi.save()

   return redirect('/backoffice')

else:
 form = CreaSchedaForm()


context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "crea_scheda.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this would be using the bulk_create method on the object manager with an array/list of the objects to be created

example

```
ModelName.objects.bulk_create([
    ModelName(title="Model1"),
    ModelName(title="Model2"),
    ModelName(title="Model3"),
])
```

where ModelName refers to the Name of Your Model, and ModelName within the list refers to the different instances/records of the ModelName class/database to be create in a bulk

Comment: I've already seen bulk create but I have to insert the data dynamically